# Remote Desktop - changing between single and dual monitors on the fly

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Before connecting to Remote Desktop, you can choose to use both monitors.

[image: Option to use all monitors]

How do you change this setting **after you are connected**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up RDP (all options) before connecting. That is the way you make it work. So set up the Monitor settings (and indeed other settings like local resources) before you connect.